# How should people trust an online store?

Tags: united-states, online-banking, online-payment, regulation, online-shopping

As I understood and experienced in the US, when we want to buy something online, the online store website asks for complete name, card number, expiration date and even the security code(CVV) on the card. I think everybody can use the other's card with knowing this information. So, how can we trust to online stores to give them our card information?

Also, if I want to launch a new online store, how do other people trust my website and give me all their card information? What if I use this information to steal their money?

Is there any place people they want to launch an online store should go there and get some permissions before launching an online store or anybody can launch a website and ask the card information of people?

Answer (score 6):

Almost always the online stores use a payment gateway such as PayPal, Stripe, or one of many others.  These are widely trusted and due to the way they work the store never even gets your card details directly (they may get a token from the gateway to allow them to reuse the card).

The trust & reputation such as whether the store sends the goods ordered and they are of adequate quality etc. *is* the concern of the store itself.  Thankfully (because I don't know) the art of building reputation is not directly relevant to finance & money so I will skip that part :)

Comment: I'm not sure that "Almost always" stores use third-party services and don't get the actual card info. I use many sites that just have payment services built into their site (meaning I don't connect to paypal or other services) and my card info is saved on their side (meaning they aren't just used for the transaction and thrown away). I agree with the rest of the answer though.

Answer (score 3):

"Trust but verify"

If a company takes your credit card info and uses it for purchases that you didn't authorize, that's *fraud* and it's illegal. With social media, companies that do this would not last long, which is why you see the exact same "scam" sites pop up with different names and URLs all the time.

Credit card companies also have "fraud protection" that let you dispute and not be liable for charges that you did not authorize. It would be a hassle but you can more than likely get unauthorized charged removed. The few times it's happened to me the card company actually credit my account immediately while they investigated, so I didn't have to worry about paying the fraudulent charges or accruing interest.

Your mileage may vary, and if you are fearful of giving your card info online, then you can also find cards that let you create "single use" card numbers, or stick to sites that use trusted third-party payment options like PayPal.

Comment: It's worth noting that thanks to a law in the United States, (the Fair Credit Billing Act) a consumer has 60 days from receipt of a statement to report fraud to the card issuer for investigation, and consumer liability is limited to $50 (though most CC's set it at $0).  It's not credit card companies doing this out of the kindness of their hearts; but it is a reduction of risk to the consumer created by political policy, which makes the first move in terms of trust of a new retailer easier to occur.

Answer (score 1):

A way to minimize, perhaps eliminate this user risk is to utilize a credit card that offers Virtual Account Numbers.  It generates a unique credit card number and you can set a dollar amount and an expiration date.  Whatever you charge on this VAN is then billed to you on your regular credit card.